# open another div when click on one incremental numbered div

Tags: php, javascript, html

I have a script that when i click on one div, will make another div show or hide.

That works great, but when i use that in an sql query and i click on one div, all the other ones will show :)
So i was thinking at an incremental script so that it will auto number the div automatically (which works great) but i don't know what to use inside java script so that it will work.

Here is the code:

```
<?php
$conn = mysql_connect("localhost","user","pass");
mysql_select_db("database");
mysql_set_charset("UTF8", $conn);
$a = 1;
$b = 1;?>
<script>
$(".Denumire<?php echo $a; ?>").click(function(){
$(".Informatie<?php echo $b; ?>").toggle();
})

</script><?php
$construct ="SELECT * FROM tablename ";
$run = mysql_query($construct) or die(mysql_error());
$foundnum = mysql_num_rows($run);
// Define $color=1
$color="1";
if ($foundnum==0)
{
echo "Nu avem Informații!";
}
else
{

while($runrows = mysql_fetch_assoc($run))
{
$Denumire = $runrows ['Denumire'];
$Informatie = $runrows ['Informatie'];

echo "

<div id='dam'>
<div class='Denumire".$a++."'>
<table>
<tr>
<td>$Denumire</td>
<td><img src='http://bios-diagnostic.ro/wordpress/img/gobottom.png'></td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>
<div class='Informatie".$b++."'><br>$Informatie<br></div>
</div><hr><br><br>
";}}?>
```

The problem is in the java script... Some ideas will be appreciated ... thank you all.

Comment: at line 7 there's a $a++ but it's outside php tags, is it correct?

Comment: Do you want $(".Denumire1") to open and close $(".Denumire2") and $(".Denumire2") to open and close $(".Denumire3") and so on ...?

Comment: I want $(".Denumire1") to open and close $(".Informatie1") and $(".Denumire2") to open and close $(".Informatie2") and so on...

Comment: did this so far... $a = 1;
$b = 1;?>
<script>
$(".Denumire<?php echo $a; ?>").click(function(){
    $(".Informatie<?php echo $b; ?>").toggle();
}) and modified <div class='Informatie'><br>$Informatie<br></div> with <div class='Informatie".$b++."'><br>$Informatie<br></div> and the first div closes the first info... but the seccond div does nothing...

Comment: could you please update the question code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a siblings method in jquery and I believe it works great, so the javascript should be

```
<script>
$(".Denumire").click(function(){
    $(this).siblings(".Informatie").toggle();
})
</script>
```

and the display part

```
<div class='Denumire".$a++."'>
```

should be

```
<div class='Denumire'>
```

hope this work :D

[edit]

To close the others:

```
<script>
$(".Denumire").click(function(){
    $(".Informatie").hide();
    $(this).siblings(".Informatie").show();
})
</script>
```